# flutter application is not created even after the andrroid and flutter plugin installation setup

Tags: plugins, installation

flutter application is not created even after the android and flutter plugin installation setup.

I have followed the following steps as given in the link
[Flutter Installatioon steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

I dont know where I went wrong,. which installation steps  I have missed.

My system is windows 32 bit.

I am encllosing the required screen shots[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0du90.jpg)

[my system configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FGl8.jpg)
[User Variable. path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pApY.jpg)

Pleasee help me by fixing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using Git instead of command line (cmd) and fix the path for flutter you should get the correct address for that for example: C:\flutter\bin